# Proving that $\int_a^\infty e^w \phi_{\mu,\sigma}(w)dw = e^{A+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} \Phi(\frac{\mu+\sigma^2 - a}{\sigma})$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We have been given this equality in a class, and I would like to prove it.

$$\int_a^\infty e^w \phi_{\mu,\sigma}(w)dw = e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} \Phi(\frac{\mu+\sigma^2 - a}{\sigma})$$

Where $\phi$ is the normal pdf with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal (0,1) CDF.

The teacher's assistant refused to prove it but said, OK it is so easy, and can be done using first principles and a change in variables. Here is the proof I came up with.

> $$e^z f(z) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{z-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}$$ And define the indefinite integral
> (used Mathematica). $$\int \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{z-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{z - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2} dz =
> -\frac{1}{2} e ^{(\sigma^2 / 2 + \mu)} \text{Erf} \left(\frac{\sigma^2 + \mu - z }{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \right)$$
>
> The Erf function above is the Gauss error function, defined by
> $\text{Erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z e^{-t^2} dt$. I then use
> this to evaluate the definite integral, which uses the fact that the
> Erf function has a value of -1 for $-z$ as $z$ tends to infinity.
>
> $$\int_{a}^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{z-\frac{1}{2}\left(
> \frac{z - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2} dz = -\frac{1}{2} e ^{(\sigma^2 / 2 +
> \mu)} (-1)+ \frac{1}{2} e ^{(\sigma^2 / 2 + \mu)} \text{Erf}
> \left(\frac{\sigma^2 +u - a }{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \right) $$ $$ =
> \frac{1}{2} e ^{(\sigma^2 / 2 + \mu)}\left(1+ \text{Erf}
> \left(\frac{\sigma^2 +u - a }{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \right) \right)$$
>
> The Erf is related to the standard normal cumulative distribution
> function. Let $N(x)$ be the CDF for a standard normal distribution (
> to match the notation used in Björk), then
>
> $$N(x)= \frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \text{Erf}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
> \right)$$
>
> So we surely have the following relation.
>
> $$N \left( \frac{1}{\sigma} (\sigma^2 +u - a )
> \right)= \frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \text{Erf}\left( \frac{\sigma^2 +u - a
> }{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right) \right)$$
>
> So all together for this step we have evaluated the following definite
> integral. $$\int_{a}^\infty e^z f(z) dz = \int_{a}^\infty
> \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{z -
> \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2} dz = e ^{(\sigma^2 / 2 + \mu)} N \left( \frac{1}{\sigma} (\sigma^2 +u - a ) \right)$$

The T.A. was suggesting that the way I used mathematica for the indefinite integral isn't needed and this conclusion can be made in a much "simpler" manner. Perhaps with just using basic principles of the PDF, CDF, etc. I am just not seeing how I can make this conclusion without evaluating the indefinite integral as I have done above, in terms of the Erf and then converting to the CDF.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: complete the square in the exponent in your first equation ie express $e^z e^{\frac{-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ as $e^{\frac{-(z-a)^2}{2b^2}}e^k$. $k$ is a constant.

Comment: I'm sorry @balaji I am not seeing this, I am not seeing how you get $a$ and $b$ from $\mu$ and $\sigma$. If I try to combine all the terms in the numerator I just get $-z^2 + 2z(\mu + \sigma^2) - \mu^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_a^\infty e^w e^{-\frac{(w-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dw &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_a^\infty e^{-\frac{(w-\mu)^2 - 2\sigma^2w}{2\sigma^2}} dw \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_a^\infty e^{-\frac{(w^2+\mu^2-2(\mu+\sigma^2)w}{2\sigma^2}} dw \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_a^\infty e^{-\frac{(w-(\mu+\sigma^2))^2 + \mu^2 - (\mu + \sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dw \\
&= e^{\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_a^\infty e^{-\frac{(w-(\mu+\sigma^2))^2}{2\sigma^2}} dw
\end{align}

The result follows from the symmetry of Normal pdf i.e. $\Phi(-x) = 1 - \Phi(x).$

Comment: Wow thank you, That's great. I tried for a couple hours to figure that out and in the end I just wasn't seeing this factorization.